# How to prevent hidden fields with ID from getting hacked

Tags: playframework

I am building a simple CRUD app (not using the CRUD module).

My model is a simple class with one attribute. the id is implicitly inheritied from Model.

```java
@Entity
public class Account extends Model {

    @Required
    public String domain;
}
```

The view is as follows. Please note the hidden field with id.

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="@{Application.save}" method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Settings</legend>
    <input type="hidden" name="account.id" value="${account?.id}">

    #{field 'account.domain'}
    <div class="control-group #{if field.error != null} error #{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="${field.id}">&{field.name}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="${field.id}" value="${field.value}" name="${field.name}">
            <span class="help-inline">${field.error}</span>
        </div>        
    </div>
    #{/field}        

    <div class="form-actions">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

I have been able to build a scenario where save,update works.

The way update is done is I read the ID from hidden field, and update the record. If ID is not available, a new record is created.

**So the question is:** Can the ID be hacked i.e modified so that I change 1 to 2, and assuming a record with 2 exists, it gets overwritten. (I suppose it shouldn't be difficult with firebug or other plugins).

How do I prevent this? One option I thought of is to read the record with the given Id, if user is allowed to modify it, I allow update, otherwise not. This is still not fool proof because, while the user could be allowed, "wrong" record could be modified.

I imagine this is a known problem and hopefully with a known solution.

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So the question is: Can the ID be hacked i.e modified so that I change
>   1 to 2, and assuming a record with 2 exists, it gets overwritten. (I
>   suppose it shouldn't be difficult with firebug or other plugins).
>
> How do I prevent this? One option I thought of is to read the record
>   with the given Id, if user is allowed to modify it, I allow update,
>   otherwise not. This is still not fool proof because, while the user
>   could be allowed, "wrong" record could be modified.

Of course, it is possible for an attacker to change the id of the record.

there are several ways to minimize the impact of this attack.

1) easiest way - **Object fetching**:

**Fetch the Object from the database and check if it belongs to the user in question.** This will prevent other users from messing around with objects that don't belong to them, but will not prevent a user to change another object belonging to him. This is an easy way and sufficient in most cases.

2) more complicated: **signing**:

The idea here is to **sign the constants you provide to the template and check if the hash still matches after form submission.** 
 This is very similar to what play does with its session. Its impossible for an attacker to mess around with the constants (e.g. id) and provides the most security.. however, you'll have more work to do.

Example:

```
    public static void someActionDisplayingForm(){
  SomeObject o = ....
  SomeOtherObject o2 = ....
      String constants = o.id + "|" + o2.id;
      String hash = Crypto.sign(constants);
       render(o, o2, hash);
}
```

in the template you have

```
 #{form ...}
   <input type='hidden' name='id1' value='${o.id}' />
   <input type='hidden' name='id2' value='${o2.id}' />
   <input type='hidden' name='hash' value='${hash}' />
```

in the method processing the form you'll do

```
 public static void processing(String id1, String id2, String hash, String otherValues, ...){
   String constants = id1 + "|" + id2;
   String checkHash = Crypto.sign(constants);
    if(!checkHash.equals(hash))
     badRequest();
   ... 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I needed. Crypto.sign computes HMAC.SHA1 signature. I will try it out tonight. What I had been mulling with was to have user specific secret, but that is an implementation detail. You have provided clarity to the haze in my mind. Thanks :)

Comment: works like a charm. Simpler than maintaining state at the server. I plan to use user specific keys which I will generate at signup instead of the application secret which is used by default. [Sign method with 2 params](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2/play/libs/Crypto.html#sign%28java.lang.String,%20byte[]%29)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would bother. The Play framework is completely stateless. If it can figure out that only account id 1 can be modified on the GET, why can't it figure it out again on the POST? The session already identifies the user. There is no reason to encrypt anything else.

Comment: @Daniel The problem is not that Play is stateless, the problem is that binding is done simply based on the input field. If I enter 1, or 2 in id and id is the primary field, it will affect which record gets updated.  If you are referring to why I am bothering with using different keys for users, it is simply to isolate and ensure if somehow 1 key gets compromised, everyone is not affected.

Comment: I went the hash route for a bit.  It is plagued with issues.  for instance, what if the user does a GET http://xxxx.com/entity/{id} and puts an id he does not own.  clearly, the software will generate the hash correctly and the controller for that GET MUST do security code verifying that {id} is owned by the user.  Well, if you already wrote a method to do that, use that same method in your POST as well!!!  I ended up not going the hash route as it only protects on posts.  The userid is protected in the session by the session hash so we know that is valid.

Comment: oh, and I use chrome to modify the hidden fields and post back...it works great for this type of security testing.

Comment: well, if the user should not have access to /entitiy/{someId}, its your job to prevent him from seeing the page and the generated hash. 

the hash works only if you combine the hidden fields either with each other or with some string the user can not manipulate. and yes, as stated above, its a lot more work to implement for everything, but usually you don't need this level of security everywhere, but just on some places and also just for some fields.

Answer (score 2):

> Can the ID be hacked i.e modified so that I change 1 to 2, and
>   assuming a record with 2 exists, it gets overwritten. (I suppose it
>   shouldn't be difficult with firebug or other plugins).

You are correct. Editing such things can be as easy as inspecting and editing the element in Chrome's console. Remember; anything that is done client-side is insecure and can be modified by the user. Always have server-side checks, **always**.

> How do I prevent this?

One possible fix is to link records to users, i.e., create a bridging table between users and records called "recordAccess" (or whatever your naming convention leads you to call it). This bridging table will have a user ID column and a record ID column. The server will check the user ID and the record ID against this table and will only allow changes if there is a matching row in the database. How you add rows to this table depends on how your app works, but shouldn't be difficult to work out.

To prevent users from editing the wrong record, you could add an additional column into this bridging table called "current" (or, again, whatever you prefer) which is a simple boolean value. When the user goes to edit a record that he/she is allowed to edit, this value will be set to "true" and all other rows associated with that user will be set to "false". Then, when the user submits the edit, if the value in that row is set to "true", the row successfully updates and the value changes back to "false". Otherwise, all values are set to "false" and the update is rejected.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks. Right now, I am exploring a combination of this with some sort of message digest. HMAC (rfc 2104) appears to fit the bill. I need to understand it better. Will update this thread if I make any headway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be modified. It takes no real knowledge or skill to do so. In any case, information that comes from the user must not be trusted until you've verified otherwise.

In order to do that, you need some sort of server-side logic. In many cases, that's just a session linked on the server to the user object, which allows you to perform authorization (you make sure the record is one they can modify; which one matters less and is a intentionally user-caused bug, not a security risk).

So long as you can tie the request back to a user, then make sure the user is allowed to execute the request, you're good. The easiest way to do that is typically sessions, but there's a lot of room.